# results immediately disappeared - SNAP in python

Tags: python, command-prompt

I have this code from SNAP but I can't see the result as it is closed immediately after it runs:

```
import snap

Graph = snap.GenRndGnm(snap.PNGraph, 100, 1000)

snap.PlotKCoreNodes(Graph, "example", "Directed graph - k-core nodes")

UGraph = snap.GenRndGnm(snap.PUNGraph, 100, 1000)

snap.PlotKCoreNodes(UGraph, "example", "Undirected graph - k-core nodes")

Network = snap.GenRndGnm(snap.PNEANet, 100, 1000)

snap.PlotKCoreNodes(Network, "example", "Network - k-core nodes")
```

Also, I have this warning: Reloaded modules: _snap, snap

Can anyone help me?

Comment: For waiting before the program ends you can use input('Press enter to continue...') (or raw_input if you use python 2)

Comment: The documentation for [`PlotKCoreNodes`](https://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/doc/reference/PlotKCoreNodes.html) says it creates 3 files and doesn't return anything—so there may be nothing to see. For that reason and the fact that it sounds like you're running the script from the command-line, I doubt that @zohar.kom's suggestion will help much.

Comment: @martineau No, I still have the problem to run it.

Comment: In that case your question is unclear. Are you running the script from the command-line or by clicking on it? What output do you think you're not seeing—error messages or what? Are you using Python 2 or 3 (because I think snap.py only works with Python 2)?

Comment: @martineauI use spyder with python 2. I should see a plot as result. because the command prompt is closed immediately I cannot see any result. it happens for all the available code that they have on their website.

Comment: It could possibly be due to the fact that main returns shortly after the graph is created?